# Grafana is not showing average value

Tags: grafana, flux

I'm trying to get an average value from the data I've read. The bottom graph shows the data I have received so far, and the number on top should represent the average value, but at first glance, it is clear that it is not the average.

[Graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Flcur.jpg)

This is the query I have tried:

```
 from(bucket: "DP")
  |> range(start: -1d)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "forward_energy")
  |> window(every: 1d)
  |> mean()
```

Comment: It looks like you are getting mean for previous day (00-24).

Comment: If you want to see average over period shown at panel, you can add legend to your graph, and include avg there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `range(start: -1d)` and `window(every: 1d)` youl will still get more than one datapoint.
Windowing by day will use midnight (UTC if you have not set the location option) as the boundry.

If now is `2023-04-11T08:00:00Z` for example the range will get data from `2023-04-10T08:00:00Z` to `2023-04-11T08:00:00Z`, then the window will create two time-buckets: one from `2023-04-10T08:00:00Z` to `2023-04-11T00:00:00Z` and the pther from `2023-04-11T00:00:00Z` to `2023-04-11T08:00:00Z`.

The mean function will then extract the mean value for each window and you will get a single series with two datapoints: one at `2023-04-10T08:00:00Z` and the other at `2023-04-11T00:00:00Z`.

Grafana than is only showing a single point (probably the first one).

If you only care about the mean in the last day (24h) than you can skip the window function:

```
from(bucket: "DP")
  |> range(start: -1d)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "forward_energy")
  |> mean()
```